# Propel ORM - SELECT ... WHERE col1 = col2

Tags: php, orm, criteria, propel

I have been trying to port project im working on to *PropelORM*. So far so everything has been great.

However I've ran into problems with a tree structure that we have setup in one of our tables.

Pretty much if `ID = PARENTID` then its a root.
eg.

```
ID | NAME | PID
0  | ZERO | 0  
1  | ONE  | 1  
2  | TWO  | 1  
3  | THREE| 3
```

One and two are actually roots.

I tried something like this

```
$res_crit = new Criteria();  
$res_crit->add(PropertyTypePeer::ID, PropertyTypePeer::CONVERTEDID, Criteria::EQUAL);  
$result = PropertyTypePeer::doSelect($res_crit, Propel::getConnection('system'));
```

but it only returns one row where where `ID = 0` and `parent id = 0.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom criteria to achieve such a query with propel:

```
$res_crit->add(PropertyTypePeer::ID, PropertyTypePeer::ID.' = '.PropertyTypePeer::CONVERTEDID, Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

A custom criteria allows you to write custom code in your WHERE clause. In such a case, the first argument of Criteria#add does not matter (it won't be used by propel at all) but we're putting in the column we're querying on for readability's sake.

Comment: You should actually look into Propels nested set behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$res_crit->where(PropertyTypePeer::ID.' = '.PropertyTypePeer::CONVERTEDID);
```

At least less to write and seems to be more readable.

Worked for me in rather complex criteria.

**NOTE:** `$criteria->where()`, combines conditions through `AND`.

If you need custom criteria to be combined through `OR`, you need to use `$criteria->orWhere()`.